# pr2 Pick and Place Demo IK error (diamondback)

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, ros-diamondback, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to run the pr2_pick_and_place_demo on our PR2 (running diamondback).  Most of the time I can get it to locate the object, grab it, and lift its arm, but then it stops.  The error it throws is a "tuple index out of range" error.  In the manipulation stack it throws the IK error code NO_IK_SOLUTION.  Has anyone experienced this problem?  Does anyone have a good solution?

**Full Error Information** 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 532, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run() 
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 484, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs) 
File df"/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/src/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/pick_and_place_demo.py", line 300, in run_demo
result = self.move_objects_to_other_side() 
File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/src/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/pick_and_place_demo.py", line 149, in move_objects_to_other_side
(result, arm_used) = self.detect_and_pick_up_object(head_point, arms_to_try = arms_to_try, constrained = self.constrained) 
File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/src/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/pick_and_place_manager.py", line 1614, in detect_and_pick_up_object
(success, arm_used) = self.pick_up_nearest_object(arms_to_try = arms_to_try) 
File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/src/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/pick_and_place_manager.py", line 1447, in pick_up_nearest_object
(result, arm_used) = self.grasp_object_and_check_success(object_to_grasp, whicharm) 
File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/src/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/pick_and_place_manager.py", line 1326, in grasp_object_and_check_success
self.move_arm_to_side(arm_used, try_constrained = 1) 
File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/src/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/pick_and_place_manager.py", line 1664, in move_arm_to_side
result = self.try_to_move_constrained(whicharm,constraint,3,start_angles,location) 
File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_tabletop_manipulation_apps/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/src/pr2_pick_and_place_demos/pick_and_place_manager.py", line 1633, in try_to_move_constrained
error_code = self.cms[whicharm].move_arm_constrained(constraint, start_angles, location) 
File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/pr2_object_manipulation/pr2_gripper_reactive_approach/src/pr2_gripper_reactive_approach/controller_manager.py", line 599, in move_arm_constrained
joint_constraint.position = solution[2] 
IndexError: tuple index out of range

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11504/pr2-pick-and-place-demo-ik-error-(diamondback)/) by [sararielle](https://answers.ros.org/users/1012/sararielle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-10-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The NO_IK_SOLUTION means that the IK received a  manipulator pose for which there is no joints configuration (or it can't be found). You should try a different place position (which I don't think can be done with the demo).

The IndexError is probably a bug, as it means that there is no check that IK returned no solution, and it tries to access an element of an empty vector. This problem is trivial to solve (a try...except, or a if len(solution) != 0) will suffice, but I have never encountered it before.

Can you try electric and see if anything changes? Manipulation has improved a lot in the new version.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2011-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1